# Nginx regex in location block?

Tags: nginx, subdomain, proxypass

So I'm using Nginx as a reverse proxy, and my current config has gotten very long, since I have about 12 sub-domain's, and that number will continue to grow a little more.  I'm looking for a way to clean up my config, and I think I found a way but I can't get it to work.  Here is what I'm trying:

```
server {
  server_name  ~^(.+)\.domain\.com$;
  ssl  on;

  location ~ domain1 {
    proxy_pass  http://192.168.1.50:4040/;
  }

  location ~ domain2 {
    proxy_pass  http://192.168.1.60:4040/;
  }
}
```

But it's giving me an error that says

```
nginx: [emerg] "proxy_pass" cannot have URI part in location given by regular expression, or inside named location, or inside "if" statement, or inside "limit_except"
```

And I understand what it's saying, but unsure how to resolve it.  If I remove the trailing slash from the `proxy_pass` directives, Nginx will start without error but neither of the subdomains work.

Am I going about this the right way?  Is there a better way to do it?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Why not use separate `server` blocks for each `server_name`?

Comment: Why not use separate conf file for each subdomain? That's how I have it, works perfectly. I call mine sub_domain_tld.conf and when I have a new one, I copy a previous one, amend it slightly, presto.

Comment: I am currently using separate `server` blocks, but as I said, my config is growing quite large.  I have to scroll to to see all the config to verify everything is there, and it's annoying to me.  I could do separate conf files, but again, I'd have to open each of them to verify configs (some have `auth_basic`, others have different `proxy_pass` params, etc).  I'm literally hoping I can shrink my config to where I can see it all easier.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comments, the best way (most readable and fastest) is to manually configure each domain. This is because NGINX will create static entities in memory to avoid the runtime processing of each request.

However, if you really want to do this (proxy_pass to different places for different subdomains) then you can do this:

E.g.

```
map $http_host $my_upstream {
    default http://192.168.1.1:8080;
    domain1.* http://172.0.0.1:8081;
    domain2.* http://10.0.0.1:80802;
}

server {
    server_name ~(.+)\.domain\.com;

    location / {
        proxy_pass $my_upstream;
    }
}
```

Note that the `map` needs to be **outside** the server block

Comment: While this would work, it would require that all my locations have the exact same params, but that's not true unfortunately.  Some have `auth_basic`, one have `client_max_body_size`, one has `proxy_buffering  off`, etc.  Right now it works with a bunch of separate `server` blocks, but it's getting difficult to scroll through and very everything was there.  If I could do something like what I posted above, it would shrink my config and make it easier to see everything without scrolling or opening multiple configs. Sounds lazy, I know.

Comment: And thanks for the reminder that having static config would be loaded in memory, and avoiding runtime processing.